# What does the filter name I+z' mean

Tags: light, observational-astronomy, terminology

On the TRAPPIST telescope, the filter wheels are described to have a filter with the following description:

> NIR Luminance I+z' (>700nm)

After a bit of googling, I wasn't able to find what the specifics of this filter are (its FWHM and mean wavelength).

How would I go about finding these qualities of this filter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They must be referring to two different filters:

- the (Bessel) I filter which has a central wavelength of $\lambda \simeq 800\,\mathrm{nm}$  and a width of $\Delta\lambda\simeq 150\,\mathrm{nm}$, and
- the (Sloan) z' filter, which has $\lambda,\Delta\lambda \simeq 970,255\,\mathrm{nm}$.

Hence their transmission is in the near infrared ("NIR"), and they're both above 700 Å.

The exact transmission curves vary a little depending on the producer, so if you want to calculate exact magnitudes, for instance, you need to find the transmission curves for the telescope in question. From the [TRAPPIST equipment website](http://www.ati.ulg.ac.be/TRAPPIST/Trappist_main/Equipment.html), it seems they use filters from [Astrodon](http://www.astrodon.com). Astrodon don't seem to provide filter curves for these exact filter, but if you're okay with a good approximation, you can find the curves here:
[Bessel I](http://svo2.cab.inta-csic.es/theory/fps/index.php?id=NOT/ALFOSC.Bes_I&&mode=browse&gname=NOT&gname2=ALFOSC#filter) and
[Sloan z'](http://www.aip.de/en/research/facilities/stella/instruments/data/sloanugriz-filter-curves).